# Send Variable amount to Stripe without creating a product gives me Error : IntegrationError: lineItems.0.price_data is not an accepted parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

Im trying to intergrate stripe to my app. basically what i really want to do is when a stripe checkout form is created I need to send variable amount by sending my own amount entered in lineItems array. I have tried using price_data but im getting this error:

[image]

Here is my code for creating invoice using LineItems array:

```
<button
              onClick={() =>
                checkout({
                  lineItems: [
                    {
                      // price: "price_1LXN8XJK5rJC1jE3jnJyjiT3",
                      price_data: {
                        currency: "cad",
                        unit_amount: 250,
                        unit_amount: 1,
                        product_data: {
                          name: "Interviewww",
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                })
              }
            >
              Buy now!
            </button>
```

Let me what am I doing wrong here. Thanks alot community!

Comment: What endpoint are you trying to use? The [`POST /v1/invoices`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create)?

Comment: im using stripe SDK

Comment: Can i create stripe session on react js only? without using node js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are two ways of integrating with Stripe's Checkout Sessions. The first one is a [client-only integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client), the one you're currently using with the Stripe.js library. This requires for you to have pre-created prices/products since this is running on the customer's browser and it's more prone for user misusage or abuse. For more details on the accepted params you could take a look at the Stripe.js [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-lineItems-price).

On the other hand, if you're looking for a more robust approach that allows varibale amounts with no pre-defined prices/products, than you will need to integrate with the more common server-side integration described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart).

One last thing to note is that you were using the parameters of line_items described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data) which are related to the server-side integration and are not available in the Stripe.js library.

Comment: Yes couldnt find any solution for it as redirectToCheckout of stripe doesnt allow us to send variable payment and creating session for variable payment isnt available on client end side so I opted for server-side integration. Thanks alot @Tarzan for clearing out my misconception.